# Deleting rows and columns of a data frame based on values of another data frame

Tags: r, list, loops, dataframe

I want to print the rows and columns of a large data frame in which the values appear also in a given row or column of another data frame. I am trying a for loop based on the coincidence with a list of values, without success. A simplified example:

Given the data frame

```
r1<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
r2<-c(6,7,8,9,10)
r3<-c(11,12,13,14,15)
r4<-c(16,17,18,19,20)
r5<-c(21,22,23,24,25)
sample<-as.data.frame(rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5))

        V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
   r1   1   2   3   4   5
   r2   6   7   8   9   10
   r3   11  12  13  14  15
   r4   16  17  18  19  20
   r5   21  22  23  24  25
```

I want to erase the columns of "sample" in which the values of the first row r1 do not appear in

```
info.column<-as.data.frame(c(6,1,4,21,15,11,9,12,13,14,15))
```

and to erase the rows in which the values of the first column V1 do not appear in

```
info.row<-as.data.frame(c(1,11,3,7,5,21,2))
```

The expected result would be

```
            V1  V4
       r1   1   4
       r3   11  14
       r5   21  24
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a very basic question.  Can you share what you've tried and where you have looked that you have not found an appropriate answer?

Comment: I am sorry if it is too basic. Can you please direct me to a similar problem? I have searched quite a long time, specifically on how to make a list out of, respectively info.column and info.row, to later apply a for loop. But as said before it is not working. Any help is very welcomed.

Comment: Subsetting data sets in `R` is covered thoroughly in every intro guide available.  In the future please do a bit of research before posting to SO.  `sample[sample$V1 %in% info.row[, 1], sample[1,] %in% info.column[, 1]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sample[sample$V1 %in% info.row[, 1], sample[1,] %in% info.column[, 1]]`

Lets break that down.  Look at what each portion returns:

```
> sample$V1 %in% info.row[, 1]
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

This says what rows of the column of `sample` named `V1` are found in the first column of the data.frame `info.row`. Or in words, I find matching values in rows 1, 3 and 5.

Similarly:

```
> sample[1,] %in% info.column[, 1]
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Says I want the columns of `sample` where the first column of your data.frame `info.column` is found in the first row. Again in words, I find values matching in columns 1 and 4.

So the result will be 3 x 2 and equivalent to `sample[c(1, 3, 5), c(1, 4)]`

When using `[` you can read that as `subset`.  So return the [rows, columns] where those two expressions are `TRUE`

Comment: Thanks a lot, obviously I was to obsessed looking for a for loop based on a list of values, it was much simpler than that.